# Change image on input change using jQuery switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, switch-statement

I am creating a font example that will change on option select. It doesn't however, appear to be working. I've used a similar format for a previous problem but somehow it doesn't seem to be responding this time around.. Thanks!

```
<div class="form-input">
<label class="label" for="font-choice">Not sure which font? Choose from our top 12: </label>
<select class="form-select" id="engraving-type">
<option style="font-family: Arial" value="Arial">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Arial</option>
<option style="font-family: Baskerville" value="Baskerville"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Baskerville</option>
<option style="font-family: Baroness Bold" value="Baroness Bold"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Baroness Bold</option>
<option style="font-family: Cantania" value="Cantania"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cantania</option>
<option style="font-family: Century Gothic" value="Century Gothic"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Century Gothic</option>
<option style="font-family: Chinese" value="Chinese"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Chinese</option>
<option style="font-family: Edwardian Script" value="Edwardian Script"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Edwardian Script</option>
<option style="font-family: Dagobent" value="Dagobent"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Dagobent</option>
<option style="font-family: Goudy" value="Goudy"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Goudy</option>
<option style="font-family: Palatino" value="Palatino"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Palatino</option>
<option style="font-family: Baroness Bold" value="Baroness Bold"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Baroness Bold</option>
<option style="font-family: Times New Roman" value="Times New Roman"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Times New Roman</option>
</select>
</div>


<div class="form-input">
<label class="label" for="form-table">Font example:</label><span id="text-example"><img id="font-image" src="/images/fonts/Font-Baskerville.jpg" /></span>
</div>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#engraving-type").change(function(){
    switch (this.value) {
    case 'Arial': 
        var image = 'Font-Arial.jpg'; 
        break;
    case 'Baskerville': 
       var image = '/#'; 
        break;
    default:
       var image = 'Font-Baskerville.jpg'; 
        break;
    }
    $( "#font-image" ).attr("src", "/images/fonts/" + image);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: if alert(image) what you get ? please try and tell me

Comment: it work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/u3pjujab/

Comment: Please make your you added jquery library ?

Comment: Hmm it doesn't alert. May be something wrong with the case statement?

Comment: How weird. The jQuery library is added. it's just a no go.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u3pjujab - look the fiddle it works

Comment: It turns out I had multiple #engraving-type id's on the page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

replace this line

```
switch (this.value)
```

with

```
switch ($(this).val())
```

Comment: both scenario are correct.one is plain javascript and another jquery